# Pandas line graph - y-axis high values at the bottom and low values at the top (fliped 180 degree)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am new to pandas and just want to show my rank vs my friends rank using pandas.
And because a lower Rank is better than a higher rank (the #1 = better then #2)
I want the graph to rising and not to fall. With the code I have, the graph is falling... Please help.

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Me" : [10,9,7,6,3,2,1],
    "My friend" : [20,19,18,15,14,10,6]},
    index=list(range(7)))
lines = df.plot.line()
plt.show()
```

So over time I gain a higher rank but pandas is making a falling graph instead of a rising.
I hope you understand what I mean. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `invert_yaxis`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lines = df.plot.line(ax=ax)
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You can also do this `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was what I was looking for <3